# Adding same string string repeatedly to a list to make it a tuple

Tags: python, zip

I'm trying to combine a string with a series of numbers as tuples to a list.

For example, starting with:

```
a = [12,23,45,67,89]  
string = "John"
```

I want to turn that into:

```
tuples = [(12,'John'),(23,'John'),(45,'John'),(67,'John'),(89,'John')]
```

I tried:

```
string2 = string * len(a)
tuples = zip(a, string2)
```

but this returned:

```
tuples = [(12,'J'), (23,'o'), ...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> a = [12,23,45,67,89]
>>> string = "John"
>>> my_tuple = [(i,string) for i in a]
>>> print my_tuple
```

You can iterate over each position within a string so `zip` causes the behavior you were seeing previously.

Comment: @Daniel You're welcome. Also, I would recommend using a name other than tuple - tuple is the name of the function which is used by python to create tuples, so it's best not to overwrite it.

Comment: Yeah, I just used "Tuple" on here just to be more clear rather than the ones I am currently working with.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `zip()`, then create a list for your string variable before multiplying:

```
string2 = [string] * len(a)
tuples = zip(a,string2)
```

`string * len(a)` creates *one long string*, and `zip()` then iterates over that to pull out individual characters. By multiplying a list instead, you get a list with `len(a)` separate references to the `string` value; iteration then gives you `string` each time.

You could also use [`itertools.repeat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) to give you `string` repeatedly:

```
from itertools import repeat

tuples = zip(a, repeat(string))
```

This avoids creating a new list object, potentially quite large.